# Mean value proof in Evans PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Here is the proof

[image]

[image]

I don't really understand about the part beginning using Green's formula. How can $Du(y)$ become $du/dv$. Is it using the directional derivative formula? Also, how can you get/pull out the $r/n$? It seems to me he is using divergent theorem here.

Comment: Yes, we're using the directional derivative formula.  I think the $\frac{r}{n}$ comes from the fact that we are computing averages over balls and surfaces here.  Note that $r^n = \frac{r}{n} n r^{n-1}$.

Comment: If we are using the directional derivative formula, why (y-x)/r is the directional vector ? Can you elaborate more on the ball and surface stuff ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A key point here, which might be causing some confusion, is that the dash through the integral sign indicates that we are computing a mean value.  It's different than just a regular integral sign.

$B(x,r)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.  If $y \in \partial B(x,r)$, then 
$n = \frac{y - x}{r}$ is the outward pointing unit normal vector to $\partial B(x,r)$ at $y$.
The directional derivative of $u$ at $y$ in the direction $n$ is equal to $\nabla u(y) \cdot n$.

From the divergence theorem,
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial B(x,r)} \nabla u(y) \cdot n \, dS(y)
&= \int_{B(x,r)} \text{div } \nabla u(y) \, dy \\
&= \int_{B(x,r)} \Delta u(y) \, dy.
\end{align}

Let $c$ be the measure of the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$.  The measure
of $B(x,r)$ is $c r^n$.  The "surface area" of $\partial B(x,r)$ is $c n r^{n-1}$.
(For example, the volume of a ball in $R^3$ is $(4/3) \pi r^3$, and the surface area of a sphere is $4 \pi r^2$.)

From the above equation, it follows that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{cn r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)} \nabla u(y) \cdot n \, dS(y)
= \frac{r}{n} \frac{1}{cr^n} \int_{B(x,r)} \Delta u(y) \, dy.
\end{equation}
This is the equation at issue in your question. You can see now where the factor of $\frac{r}{n}$ comes from.

Comment: When you say: $n=\frac{y-x}{r}$ is the outward pointing unit normal vector to $\partial B(x,r)$, how do you say that? Do you consider the Cartesian equation of the ball and consider the gradient on the norm or is there a faster way?

Comment: @Natmath Hmm, it’s visually intuitive if we picture a ball in $\mathbb R^3$. Note that $y - x$ is the displacement vector from the center of the ball to the point $y$ on the boundary of the ball. I’m picturing an arrow that starts at $x$ and ends at $y$. The length of the arrow is $r$, so $(y-x)/r$ is a unit vector.

Comment: For a rigorous proof, maybe a nice way to do it is to note that $\partial B$ is a level set of the function $f(y) = \| y - x \|^2$, then invoke a theorem which states that if $y$ is a point in this level set then $\nabla f(y)$ is normal to the level set at $y$. Books on smooth manifolds typically mention that theorem, I believe. Since $\nabla f(y) = 2(y - x)$, we see that the vector $y-x$ is normal to $\partial B$ at the point $y$.